# jQuery .map() to multi-dimensional object 

Tags: jquery, object, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get a multidimensional object output from .map(), the final format I would like to get something like `{ "key" : { key : value, key : value }, "key" { key : value, key : value }, ... }`.

Here's some code http://pastie.org/1524749

I've tried in different ways without success since when I send it through ajax, I get array undefined in PHP

```
var arrData = $('#orDetColProducts .lineBottomRow').map(function(){
  intRef = $(this).find('._ref').text();
  intPrice = $(this).find('._intPrice').text();
  intQuantity = $(this).find('.existStock').val();

  if (intRef && intQuantity) {
    return '{' + intRef + ' :  { quantity : ' + intQuantity + ', price : ' + intPrice + '}' + '}';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var arrData = $('#orDetColProducts .lineBottomRow').map(function() {
    var intRef = $(this).find('._ref').text();    
    var intPrice = $(this).find('._intPrice').text();
    var intQuantity = $(this).find('.existStock').val();
    var tmp = {};
    if (intRef && intQuantity) {
        tmp.intRef = { quantity: intQuantity, price: intPrice };
    }
    return tmp;
}); // chain .get() to convert to array
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your atention! I see your point, but when I try to use this arrData on jquery.ajax I get array undifined on php. The output on console.log is [Object { intRef={...}}, Object { intRef={...}}]; I'll keep trying, based on your tip!

Comment: Also tryed to tested with var arrData = {"66949":{ quantity:7,price:200}, "343235":{ quantity: 12, price: 100}}; and this one works fine on php